# Boost.log V1 Compilation Error

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, boost-log

Experiencing difficulty in compiling boost.log v1 in my code, though I know that the issue is due to boost.filesystem v3 lack of support. I know I need to `#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 2` but where should I define it?

The compilation error:

```
error: 'external_string_type' is not a member of 'boost::filesystem3::wpath'
```

`#define` was added @ path.hpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this preprocessor `#define` two ways:

a) on the compiler command line, usually something like

```
-DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=2
```

b) before including any of the boost filesystem header files in your sources:

```
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 2
```

Comment: Yes, that'll work. Anyway, boost.log has been updated to support fielsystem v3. Thanks y'all.